# Does all openMp c++ programming compiled using -fopenmp running on GPU?

Tags: c++, openmp

I am new to openMP programming. While doing some basic examples, the cpp file is compiled using `-fopenmp`. `#pragma omp parallel` is giving at the beginning for parallelism. Also the `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)` can be given. Does all the code in this format uses GPU? From Nvidia command  `540MiB /  2002MiB`  is used. So may the GPU is not using. What should be the reason?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: OpenMP uses no GPU.

Comment: OpenMP 4.5 has support for GPU with the "target" directive, for example #pragma omp target. In your case, I doubt that you use any GPU since there is no target. Could you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does all the code in this format uses GPU?

No, it does not use the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

OpenMP 4 and higher has support for offloading computation to *accelerators* including GPUs, if your compiler supports it for your particular GPU. You have to explicitly tell OpenMP to do so; the normal pragmas continue to stick to multithreading and vectorizing on the CPU.

Here's a presentation I found with some [examples](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/presentation/s6510-jeff-larkin-targeting-gpus-openmp.pdf) (PDF warning).